# header/footer in xlwt (python).

Tags: python, xlwt

Hi!

I'm creating excel files with python, using the xlwt package. I was wondering, is there any way to set specific header / footers to every sheet using this module?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sheet = book.get_sheet(0)
sheet.header_str = 'what you prefer'
sheet.footer_str = 'things'
```

you can do it for all sheets in book with a simple for statement.

```
for s in book.sheets():
    s.header_str = 'what you prefer'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The topic was so old i wasn't even hoping to get a response anymore :d.